# How to including Microsoft Hotfix in our Wix based installers?

Tags: wix, wix3.5, hotfix, launching

We need to deliver [Hotfix KB982638](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB982638) to our clients due to a requirement in our products. Our installers are based on WIX.

How can we launch [Hotfix KB982638](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB982638)  from our installers, at the end of installation?

**What we tried:**
We tried to launch its .exe from within our .msi, but it started waiting to finish our msi process, which was actually waiting for hotfix to finish its process and so both halted.

Here is the code:

```
      <Binary Id="NDP40_x64" SourceFile="D:\ApBuild\src\bpf\extras\bin\NDP40-KB982638-x64.exe" />
      <CustomAction Id="NDP40_x64_install" Return="ignore" Execute="deferred" BinaryKey="NDP40_x64" ExeCommand=" " />

      <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="NDP40_x64_install" After="InstallFiles"><![CDATA[Not REMOVE]]></Custom>
      </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

We also tried to launch it from a Bootstrapper (setup.exe) while turning off Hotfix restart option and enabling Bootstrapper's option with Defr attribute, but in this case, if system is restarted, installation of Hotfix also restarts and so a loop is created.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks and best regards
Farrukh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I was able to solve it. The Hotfix installer itself installing *.msp files and we can't launch these from out msi installer, it hangs always.

Solution is to pack it with Setup.exe (bootsrapper application ) and installs before launching the msi.

So I launched Hotfix while passing parameter to not to restart until it finished and then I launched the msi which has a scheduled restart custom action.

Thanks a bunch guys
Farrukh

Answer (score 0):

Schedule your CA launching the hotfix after InstallFinalize. It should not wait for your installation to finish.

Comment: Dan, thanks for reply. 
Actually we can't do that. Here is what if we do that:

`code` error LGHT0204 : ICE77: NDP40_x64_install is a in-script custom action.  It must be sequenced in between the InstallInitialize action and the InstallFinalize action in the InstallExecuteSequence table